# What happens when you have both an A Record and a Name Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, http

So, I have a friend trying to do something funky between his primary domain and subdomains. He ultimately needs blog.hisdomain.com to point to a silly cPanel host and his primary domain to point to a static IP (for AWS).

I'm not an expert with http or dns, but I was trying to help him through it while he was up (it's night time in his country at present), but it doesn't really look like it's working out.

I had him perform the following steps:

1. His primary domain was set up in cPanel with nameservers set, so I had him create a subdomain in cPanel for blog.hisdomain.com which just went to the public root.
2. Then I had him add an A Record for "blog" with the IP of the cPanel host as the value. This made it so that we could see his blog at blog.hisdomain.com.
3. Next I had him change the "@" A Record to point elsewhere. I just grabbed a google IP address for the value here. This didn't really change anything at first, but we figured it might have been a propagation issue.

It's now been over 24 hours and his primary domain still (more slowly now) takes me to the blog. Just now I remembered that I didn't have him change his nameservers or anything; just the A Record. **Is it possible that having an A Record and Name Servers is causing some confusion and is leading the dns to ignore the A Record IP address.**

Answer (score 1):

No.  It is perfectly valid (and quite common) for A records and NS records to coexist for the @ record.

What is not valid, however, is for CNAME records to coexist with any other type of record.  RFC 1034 states "if a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot be different".  I ran into this particular problem recently and was dumbfounded that a TXT record and a CNAME record cannot coexist.

A couple of things I would do:

- Flush your DNS resolver cache

  - Windows: ipconfig /flushdns
  - Linux: sudo service nscd restart
  - Mac OS X

    - Mountain Lion and Lion: sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
    - Snow Leopard: sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
- I would make sure your friend is using an A record and not a CNAME record
- I would have your friend check the TTL on the @ record (or on the zone itself) - you didn't mention what the TTL was.  While 86400 seconds (24 hours) is a common TTL value, it's always possible that it is set much higher to cut down on DNS traffic.
- Use a DNS query utility (e.g. dig) to query the DNS server directly

Comment: Hmm... Nothing's changed yet. Maybe GoDaddy is trying to make good on their 48hr propagation threat. 

Are you sure the NS records and the A Records will coexist even if the "@" property in the A record points to an IP on a completely different server?